# Mapping many-to-one in YAML

Tags: ruby, rake, yaml

I'm trying to introduce a many-to-one kind of mapping inside a YAML configuration file for rake.

That is, I have something like:

```
- server: address
```

and I'd like to have something like:

```
- server: {1, 3, 5: address1; 2, 8, 12: address2}
```

of course, this is not the correct syntax.

This because I need a different address according to a given ID.

```
CONFIG['server'][3] # this should return 'address1'
CONFIG['server'][5] # this should return 'address1' too
CONFIG['server'][12] # and this should return 'address2'
```

Is this feasibile in some way?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work this way:

create a file in config called server_config.yml:

```
common: &common
  common_stuff_foo: foo
  common_stuff_bar: bar

server:
  1: 
    <<: *common
    adress: adress_for_server1

  2:
    <<: *common
    adress: adress_for_server2
  ... #some other servers

  12:
    <<: *common
    adress: adress_for_server12
```

put a file to config/initializers like config_servers.rb with the content

```
CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/server_config.yml")
```

and you might get your address via

```
CONFIG['server'][1]['address'] in your application
```

It's not tested, but I think it will work. I'm just a little bit uncertain about those numbers in the yaml-file

Comment: hmm, in your above example I think that its a little typo that CONFIG['server'][2] # this should return 'address1' Are you sure about that or did I misunderstood?